# Tables v. Bit Twiddling

Tags: performance, bit-manipulation, relational-database

I have a table with 125,000 rows and 18 columns.  Eight of the columns have just 0 and 1 as possible values.  I could do some bit manipulation and store these 8 values in a single byte, thus eliminating 7 columns. Is it worth doing so from an execution time perspective?  How would that perspective change if my table grew to 4,000,000 rows?

Comment: Depends on database engine quite a lot. Some engines already store bits packed.

Comment: Speaking only for myself, I wouldn't be concerned with the execution time my company might save on this kind of design. I'd be concerned with the man-hours I'd lose after finding this kind of design in production, then having to hunt down the designer and poke him in the eye with a sharp stick.

Comment: Back in the 1970s the SPITBOL implementation of SNOBOL did exactly this optimization automatically.  Today databases do it - and it is especially interesting in databases for answering queries where values in these columns are logically anded and ored together - e.g., your query is SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (C2 = TRUE AND C4 = FALSE) OR (C3 = C5) ...  In fact, [here's documentation for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) that explains it is automatically doing exactly this optimization _for you_ - declare your column as `bit` and it'll do it for you ...